# Make git-hook call cmd.exe without waiting for that process to finish

Tags: windows, bash, git, cmd, githooks

On a windows computer, I am adding a git-hook that starts a build; this needs to be run through cmd.exe, and I do not want the git-hook script to wait for that to finish executing, as that would mean each push would take a long time to finish.

To reproduce the problem, run these commands in an empty directory from git bash on windows:

```
mkdir githooks && cd githooks/
git init --bare
cd ..
git clone githooks clone
cd clone
git commit --allow-empty -m "1"
```

And save the following to ./githooks/hooks/update

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd.exe /c "sleep 2"
exit 1;
```

In the git bash window, from the clone directory I left you in, run `git push`. Note that ending the update script with `exit 1;` is convenient as you can re-run the git push after every edit to the git-hook script.

I have tried every combination I can think of for the two methods of "not waiting for the called script to exit"; in bash, you append an ampersand &:

```
cmd.exe /c "sleep 2" &
```

in cmd.exe (bat files), you would `start` the line:

```
cmd.exe /c "start \"title\" sleep 2"
```

I would expect either of these approached to work - i.e. the `git push` should fail quickly, rather than wait 2 seconds before failing.

Nesting cmd's does not seem to affect this:

```
cmd.exe /c "cmd.exe /c \"start \"\" sleep 2\"" &
```

When submitting an answer, be sure to also check that the command given to cmd.exe actually executes, by replacing `sleep 2` with e.g. `mkdir ..\foo` so that you can check that, not only does the script finish quickly when given a sleep command, but when given a mkdir command, the directory is actually created.

```
cmd.exe /c "mkdir ..\foo"
```

For instance, the following finishes immediately, but that is because the sleep 2 never gets executed, as /c needs the next parameter to be quoted.

```
cmd.exe /c start \"title\" sleep 2
```

Comment: There is no `sleep` command in `cmd.exe`, and I think you are using superfluous escaping in `start \"title\" ...`...

Comment: if you install git for windows, and run cmd.exe from bash (getting environment from git bash), sleep refers to `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sleep.exe`. The escaping is necessary for bash to actually pass the double quotes to cmd.exe; otherwise, I get a window titled " sleep 2" (starting with a space, no quotes in the title)

Comment: "The git-hook script is written in bash because githooks must not have an extension" It just needs to executable. It can be written in any language.

Comment: GitHooks are meant to check something, and then exit(0) or exit(1). Do you need to have everything locally? And if yes, can you install a Jenkins or something similar? Then your hook will just trigger the CI. Ideally, after your push, your SCM should trigger your CI actually.

Comment: you are right; any language would do. I was trying to clarify why I wasn't using a .bat but that has other problems being called from git directly. I've removed that from the question as it is irrelevant.

Comment: @Lovato No, I cannot install Jenkins or something similar; this script is intended to address what I need by calling (instead of the "sleep 2" command above) tfs.exe with parameters, which starts a build.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same thing and eventually got an idea to call another bash script with:

```
sh $(pwd)/.git/hooks/runCmd.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Which calls the CMD script I want and passes the argument.
Body of the bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
start "Path\MyCmd.cmd" hook
exit 0
```

Path in this case is relative to the repository root.